# How to plot a time series plot for each party and the total votes they got each year

Tags: python, plotly

[image]Here's my dataset

Newbie here
I want to plot the total votes each party has got for each year, I think bar plot would be a good fit here but I'm not understanding how to do it.

I want to do it with plotly.
The output should be something like this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is working sample for you use case

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Partyname': ['Independents', 'INC','Independents','Independents','Independents'], 'Year': [1977, 1977,1980,1980,1980], "totPoll":[25168,35400,109,125,405]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
grpByParty = df.groupby(['Partyname'])
sumVotes = grpByParty['totPoll'].agg(np.sum)

y_values = sumVotes.keys().tolist()
y_pos = np.arange(len(y_values))

votes = sumVotes.tolist()
plt.bar(y_pos, votes, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, y_values)
plt.ylabel('votes')
plt.title('party wise votes ')

plt.show()
```

Approach that have taken here

- Group the data as a party wise.
- Get sum of the total vote as party wise using aggregate.
- Take The x any y coordinates in a list.
- Plot the diagram using  matplotlib.pyplot

[image]

Output will look like this.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I want to plot for each year